# MPI_Scatter produces write error, bad address (3)

Tags: c, mpi

I am receiving a writing error when trying to scatter a dynamically allocated matrix (it is contiguous), it happens when more than 5 cores are involved in the computation. I have placed printfs and it occurs in the scatter, the code is the next:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int err = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  MPI_Comm world;
  world=MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  int size = 0;
  err = MPI_Comm_size(world, &size);

  int rank = 0;
  err = MPI_Comm_rank(world, &rank);

  int n_rows=2400, n_cols=2400, n_rpc=n_rows/size;
  float *A, *Asc, *B, *C; //Dyn alloc A B and C
  
  Asc=malloc(n_rpc*n_cols*sizeof(float));
  B=malloc(n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(float));
  C=malloc(n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(float));
  A=malloc(n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(float));
  if(rank==0)
  {        
    for (int i=0; i<n_rows; i++) 
    {
      for (int j=0; j<n_cols; j++) 
      {
        A[i*n_cols+j]= i+1.0;      
        B[i*n_cols+j]=A[i*n_cols+j];
      }
    }
  }

  struct timeval start, end;
  if(rank==0) gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
  
  MPI_Bcast(B, n_rows*n_cols, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  
  if(rank==0) printf("Before Scatter\n"); //It is breaking here
  MPI_Scatter(A, n_rpc*n_cols, MPI_FLOAT, Asc, n_rpc*n_cols, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if(rank==0) printf("After Scatter\n");
  /* Some computation */
  err = MPI_Finalize();
  if (err) DIE("MPI_Finalize");
  
  return err;
}
```

Upto 4 cores, it works correctly and performs the scatter, but with 5 or more it does not, and I can not find a clear reason.

The error message is as follows:

```
[raspberrypi][[26238,1],0][btl_tcp_frag.c:130:mca_btl_tcp_frag_send] mca_btl_tcp_frag_send: writev error (0xac51e0, 8)
    Bad address(3)

[raspberrypi][[26238,1],0][btl_tcp_frag.c:130:mca_btl_tcp_frag_send] mca_btl_tcp_frag_send: writev error (0xaf197048, 29053982)
    Bad address(1)

[raspberrypi:05345] pml_ob1_sendreq.c:308 FATAL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use `sendcount=recvcount=n_cols*n_rpc`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ohh, I thought sendcount= the real size of the matrix. Thanks! I am changing that.

Comment: Okay, so that made the code to have a better performance, as less memory is used, but the error persists

Comment: Without seeing your updated code we can't tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I edited the code 18 minutes ago, or do I have to do it in the comments instead? Sorry, I am new.
`MPI_Scatter(A, n_rpc*n_cols, MPI_FLOAT, Asc, n_rpc*n_cols, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

Comment: use `MPI_DOUBLE` with `double`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks, I already solved it, in fact, it was solved at your first comment so I have to apology myself (also with writing double instead of float).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple errors, first of all, take care of using always the same type when defining variables. Then, when you use scatter, the send count and receive are the same, and you will be sending Elements/Cores. Also when receiving with gather you have to receive the same amount you sent, so again Elements/Cores.